# Unique ID of MKLocalSearch result?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mklocalsearch

My App shows the result of a `MKLocalSearch` query.

The user can select such a place and say 'I like this place'.

When the user searches again (after closing the App), how can my App know that the user already likes this place?

Is there something in the result that does not depend on the locale (the same at the next search) and unique (not shared by another place at the same location)

```
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.region = mapView.region
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = query
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            // do I know some items in the response?
        }
```

Comment: Depends, how do you implement a user 'Liking this place'. I guess you would have to store the users liked places in core data or something similar, so just fetch these results and reference them as needed.

Comment: I use core data but that is not the problem. The problem is how to recognize the result when `MKLocalSearchRequest()` is called the next time.

Comment: Fetch a list of liked places from core data, perform the MKLocalSearchRequest and check if any of the returned, complete strings exist in your core data set. It looks like the result from the query is just a list of strings that match, no unique id

Comment: I already do this. The question is: which strings or whatever can I use to compare when I have no unique ID?

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding here but `MKLocalSearchRequest` has a completion handler `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter` which returns title, subtitle and ranges of matches. So your only option is really to use title or use a different method. maybe a [places API](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) or geocoding. If i search 'apple head' i would likely get a result Apple Headquarters, Cupertino. So I like that, if i do a similar search the same text would likely be returned in the list. so compare my Apple Headquarters, Cupertino with results.

Comment: Apple Headquarter might be Apple Hauptquartier when I search because my iPhone is set to German most of the time. Except when it is set to English for test reasons or to Spanish when I want to practice the language. Also 'McDonalds' is hard to distinguish from a McDonalds 200 meters away.

Comment: This is what the `MKLocalSearchRequest` returns. you can't change the functionality of MKLocalSearchRequest or what it returns. If this doesn't work for you then you need a different solution.

Comment: Hey @GerdCastan did you eventually get a solution to that?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca no: “Recent Similar Reports:None
Resolution:Open“. Maybe you open a radar, too?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the phone number back as part of the response, which you can use as a unique ID for the location.

Comment: That is a good answer, though different tourist info points of a city usually share the same phone number for example. I like that the phone number is not dependant on the locale.